# Tab Fragments don't show up in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs

I have a question.
I'm working with 1 activity (mainActivity) and I just switch the fragments there with a navigationView.
One of my fragments has a tabbed layout. But somehow the tabs don't show up.

This is my fragment_home.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/beige">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/home_screen"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_background"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/black"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/recipes_tab" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fav_tab" />

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabLayout">

</androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
```

This is my HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    TabItem tab1 = (TabItem) view.findViewById(R.id.tab1);
    TabItem tab2 = (TabItem) view.findViewById(R.id.tab2);
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);


    PageAdapter pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            if(tab.getPosition() == 0)
            {
                pageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else if(tab.getPosition() == 1)
            {
                pageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}
```

}

The tab's should just print out "Hello blank fragment" as you can see in the following .xml and .java codes:

fragment_tab1.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".tab1">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />
```

tab1.java

```
public class tab1 extends Fragment {

public tab1() {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understood right,you wanted to show the TabLayout in the inside the fragment not in the main fragment?

Comment: Exactly and I call this fragment in the main activity onCreate() method. And it works, but somehow the tabs don't work properly.

Comment: Ok! I have a project with the same goal. Just a minute! ;)

Comment: By the way, I suggest you to always start the class name with uppercase letter. Take a look and see if it works, and remember to set the answer as correct in the button on the left of the answer. If it's what you was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the HomeFragment

```
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inbox, container, false);

        tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.TabLayoutInBox);
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.ViewPager2InBox);

        //Set Adapter PageAdapter and glue it together
        viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapterLayout(getFragmentManager(), FragmentStatePagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT));
        //Glue TabLayout and ViewPager together
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        return view;
    }
```

You will need to create a Adapter class to switch between fragments

```
public class ViewPagerAdapterLayout extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    //How many tabs the adapter will have
    private static int COUNT = 2;

    public ViewPagerAdapterLayout(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
        super(fm, behavior);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            //Each tablayout has a number
            case 0:
                return new Tab1();
            case 1:
                return new Tab2();
            default:
                return new Tab1();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return COUNT;
    }
    
    //You can give the name of the tabs in here if u want
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
       switch (position){
           case 1:
               return "TAB 1";
           default:
               return "TAB 2";
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to keep my page title names from .xml ?

Comment: Hum, to be honest I started learning about android in December, last year so I don't know much. But I believe, it is. Sorry ;p

Comment: Ok, I have just found out how to do that. You have to replace 'tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);' with 'tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager));' and it worked for me. Just for future ;)

Answer (score 1):

So, regarding to Matheus good suggestion, I have 1 small change in the HomeFragment that needs to be changed, so the titles of your tabs, don't change when executing the program.

HomeFragment

```
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapterLayout(getFragmentManager(), FragmentStatePagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT));

    //tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager));

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));


    return view;
}
```

Doing this, you can completly remove the getPageTitle method.

I hope this helps some people as well!